# How to match the ordering and sorting of multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have data that look like this (going on for many more rows):

[image]

What I want to do is:

1. Match the relationship of **C** and **G** to the relationship of **I** and **J**.

**For example**, I:Q1652 matches up with J:Q1662; therefore, C:Q1652 should also match up with G:Q1662.

2. At the same time, **A** & **B**   and **E** & **F** should maintain their relationships with **C** and **G**, respectively

**For example**, when C:Q1652 and G:Q1662 are being matched, they should carry with them their respective rows/values from columns A & B and E & F.

Please let me know if there's anything more I can clarify! Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with vlookup and some additional columns

Comment: @TimWilliams  Hey Tim, thanks for the tip!  Unfortunately, my Excel skills aren't that sophisticated, so it's not quite clear to me how to implement vlookup to carry out this program.  Any extra info would be great.

Comment: In your graph, `J1` cell = Q1662, **NOT** Q1622.  And what is your question?

Comment: @pcw Thanks, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see K1:N1 cells in the below graph.

- K1: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I1,$C:$C,0))`
- L1: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($I1,$C:$C,0))`
- M1: `=INDEX(E:E,MATCH($J1,$G:$G,0))`
- N1: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH($J1,$G:$G,0))`

[image]

Comment: Wow, this really works! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I am glad to help.